# Batch Add-PnPFile causes memory overflow

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-online

I have a *powershell* batch script that uploads around 7.000 files into a *sharepoint* online setup.
It works, but I saw it became slower and slower.
So I monitored the script and found out, that the used memory increases by every loop pass.
I use the module **SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline**.

Any suggestions how to clear the **memory-cache**?

Thanks in advance!

```
[void] uploadFiles($_listPath){    
    $_listPath = $_listPath.Replace("\","/");
    $files = (Get-ChildItem -Path ($this._LOCAL_PATH + "\" + $_listPath));
    foreach($file in $files){
        #check if there is a file is not the related metadata file
        if($file.Name.Contains(".metadata.xml") -eq $false){
            $XmlDocument = Select-Xml -Path ($file.FullName + ".metadata.xml") -XPath "//Property";
            
            $fieldValues = @{};

            #preparing the meta data. if meta-data-field does not exists it will be created with a prefix
            foreach($i in $XmlDocument){
                if($i.node.Name -ne "FileRef" -and $i.node.Name -ne "FileDirRef" -and $i.node.Name -ne "FileLeafRef"){
                    $i.node.Name = ($i.node.Name + "_import");
                    if(!$this.fieldExists($this._LIST, $i.node.Name) -and $i.node.Name -eq "MetaInfo_import"){
                        Add-PnPField -Connection $this.connection -List $this._LIST -Type "Note" -InternalName $i.node.Name -DisplayName $i.node.Name -AddToDefaultView;
                    }elseif(!$this.fieldExists($this._LIST, $i.node.Name)){
                        Add-PnPField -Connection $this.connection -List $this._LIST -Type "Text" -InternalName $i.node.Name -DisplayName $i.node.Name -AddToDefaultView;
                    }
                    $fieldValues.($i.node.Name) = $i.node.InnerXML;
                }
            }

            #actual upload
            Add-PnPFile -Connection $this.connection -Path $file.FullName -Folder $_listPath -Values $fieldValues;
            Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName -Confirm:$false -Force;
            Remove-Item -Path ($file.FullName + ".metadata.xml") -Confirm:$false -Force;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a clear list function somewhere? This code likely does not have actual errors, but since it calls `Add-PNPFile` then some list maintained elsewhere might continuously increase in length and thus consume memory. I expect you did not perform full reinitialization of whatever this PNP library does.

Comment: I create a single object from my class. `$this.connection` is defined in the beginning of the constructor and the method `uploadFiles` is invoked in the end of the constructor. The problem does not occure with any errors but only as performance problem.